# Python Flask App - Upload Image and Display

Tags: python, html, flask

Just getting started with Python Flask App and working with HTML.

I am trying to build a simple image upload page that will display the uploaded image.  I have been able to successfully upload and save the file just not display it.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Face with ID</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">

    <h1>Upload Face (filename = face's name (i.e. John_Smith.jpg)</h1>
          <hr>

    <form action="/upload-image" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
              <label>Select image</label>
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="image"

    id="image">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">Select image...</label>
              </div>
            </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
    </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <img src="{{ uploaded_image }}">

</body>
</html>
```

FLASK APP

```
import os

from flask import Flask, redirect, jsonify, request, url_for, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"] = "C:/Flask/Upload/"


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


# Route to upload image
@app.route('/upload-image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            image = request.files["image"]
            # print(image + "Uploaded to Faces")
            # flash('Image successfully Uploaded to Faces.')
            image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename))
            filename = os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename)
            print("stored as:" + filename)
            return render_template("upload_image.html", uploaded_image=filename)
    return render_template("upload_image.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have tried to create a separate html for just displaying the image by returning the render_template and passing the uploaded_image=filename.

Ideally I would just like to display the uploaded image at the top of the page or below the submit button once uploaded.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, your `</body>` tag is misplaced.

Comment: should it be below <form>?

Comment: That closes out the `<body>`.  It should be the penultimate tag in the template, just above `</html>`

Comment: Right, so I have relocated the </body> to the line before </html> and tabbed accordingly but still no image is displayed.

Comment: <img src="/Faces/Chris_Beard.jpg" alt="Image Upload Display title"> Even with this statement The img is not displyed only the alt text.  No errors...

Comment: How are you handling calls to `/Faces/`?  Do you have an app.yaml?

Comment: I must not be handling calls.  In the examples online it demonstrates the ability to present images to the src via {{ }} or /path/to/img.jpg.  I am not aware of the handling or .yaml?  Provided the directories are within my project directory there should not be any issues with accessing the images, right?  I have read about a STATIC folder being required within templates to access any static files - is this the case?  If the app writes the uploaded images to the directory it should be able to access them to display them surely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220168/discussion-between-thomaslyit-and-gaefan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not matching your uploads directory to the view. Try this:

```
@app.route('/upload-image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            image = request.files["image"]
            image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename))
            return render_template("upload_image.html", uploaded_image=image.filename)
    return render_template("upload_image.html")


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def send_uploaded_file(filename=''):
    from flask import send_from_directory
    return send_from_directory(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], filename)
```

In your template:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('send_uploaded_file', filename=uploaded_image) }}" />
```

Comment: thank you for your help @GAEfan !!  I ened up folloing this example https://www.roytuts.com/upload-and-display-image-using-python-flask/ BUT your answer is essentially the same, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to upload, analyze, and display the image **without saving it to storage**, i.e. api and edged image analysis, this example might be a guide for you. [Flaskimio](https://github.com/geeksloth/flaskimio)

```
@app.route("/",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            print('No file attached in request')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            print('No file selected')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and check_allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            print(filename)
            img = Image.open(file.stream)
            with BytesIO() as buf:
                img.save(buf, 'jpeg')
                image_bytes = buf.getvalue()
            encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode()         
        return render_template('index.html', img_data=encoded_string), 200
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', img_data=""), 200


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="file" id="file" name="file"><input type=submit value=Upload></p>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ img_data }}" id="img-upload" alt="img_data" class="img-upload"/>
</form>
```